# Does a `DataLoader` created from `ConcatDataset` create a batch from a different files, or a single file?

Tags: pytorch

I am working with multiple files, and multiple training samples in each file. I will use `ConcatDataset` as described here:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloaders-multiple-files-and-multiple-rows-per-column-with-lazy-evaluation/11769/7

I need to have negative samples in addition to my true samples, and I need my negative samples to be randomly selected from all the training data files. So, I am wondering, would the returned batch samples just be a random consecutive chuck from a single file, or would be batch span across multiple random indexes across all the datafiles?

If there are more details needed about what I am trying to do exactly, it's because I am trying to train over a TPU with Pytorch XLA.

Normally for negative samples, I would just use a 2nd `DataSet` and `DataLoader`, however, I am trying to train over TPUs with Pytorch XLA (alpha was just released a few days ago https://github.com/pytorch/xla ), and to do that I need to send my `DataLoader` to a `torch_xla.distributed.data_parallel.DataParallel` object, like `model_parallel(train_loop_fn, train_loader)` which can be seen in these example notebooks

https://github.com/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/resnet18-training-xrt-1-15.ipynb

https://github.com/pytorch/xla/blob/master/contrib/colab/mnist-training-xrt-1-15.ipynb

So, I am now limited to a single `DataLoader`, which will need to handle both the true samples, and negative samples that need to be randomly selected from all my files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ConcatDataset` is a custom class that is subclassed from `torch.utils.data.Dataset`. Let's take a look at one example.

```
class ConcatDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, *datasets):
        self.datasets = datasets

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return tuple(d[i] for d in self.datasets)

    def __len__(self):
        return min(len(d) for d in self.datasets)

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
             ConcatDataset(
                 dataset1, 
                 dataset2
             ),
             batch_size=args.batch_size, 
             shuffle=True,
             num_workers=args.workers, 
             pin_memory=True)

for i, (input, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    ...
```

Here, two datasets namely `dataset1` (a list of examples) and `dataset2` are combined to form a single training dataset. The `__getitem__` function returns one example from the dataset and will be used by the `BatchSampler` to form the training mini-batches.

> Would the returned batch samples just be a random consecutive chuck from a single file, or would be batch span across multiple random indexes across all the datafiles?

Since you have combined all your data files to form one dataset, now it depends on what `BatchSampler` do you use to sample mini-batches. There are several samplers implemented in PyTorch, for example, `RandomSampler`, `SequentialSampler`, `SubsetRandomSampler`, `WeightedRandomSampler`. See their usage in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Sampler).

You can have your custom `BatchSampler` too as follows.

```
class MyBatchSampler(Sampler):
    def __init__(self, *params):
        # write your code here

    def __iter__(self):
        # write your code here
        # return an iterable

    def __len__(self):
        # return the size of the dataset
```

The `__iter__` function should return an iterable of mini-batches. You can implement your logic of forming mini-batches in this function.

To randomly sample negative examples for training, one alternative could be to pick negative examples for each positive example in the `__init__` function of the `ConcatDataset` class.

Comment: From the documentation, it seems for batches, you use the `BatchSampler` and you pass in the specific sampler into `BatchSampler` when you instantiate it. For my case, I want to use `RandomSampler` because it generates a list of ints that span the entire number of indexes of all of my datapoints ( https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/sampler.py#L107 ). So I think for the first code block, we would need to specify `batch_sampler = BatchSampler(RandomSampler, batch_size, drop_last)`.

Comment: But I am now wondering, how does the random sampler know the entire length of the dataset , `n`  ( https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/sampler.py#L104 ) if the each dataset is loaded lazily, to avoid loading all the files at once (to avoid memory errors). I would be implementing this `DataSet` loader https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/dataloaders-multiple-files-and-multiple-rows-per-column-with-lazy-evaluation/11769/8?u=santosh-gupta

Comment: This will require a totally new question, so I just make a new stackoverflow post.